# Find a plane with distance $3$ from $3x-y-z = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to find a plane such that its distance from the plane $3x-y-z = 0$ is $3$. Since distance is defined only for parallel planes, I already know that they have to be parallel, and then, the equation of the new plane will have the same normal vector $(3,-1,-1)$.

Also, this plane intersects the origin, because $(0,0,0)$ satisfies its equation. So my idea was to normalize the normal vector, and then multiply it by $3$. I could then put it in the origin and see it as a point of distance $3$ from the origin (and also from the plane), and then this point should be in the new plane, so it must satisfy is equation, which is:

$$3x-y-z + d = 0$$

I think this migth work, but I don't think it's the best way to solve this exercise.

A friend of mine sent me a solution like this:

$$3(x-x_0) -1(y-y_0) -1(z-z_0) = 0 \\3x -y -z + (-3x_0 +y_0+z_0) = 0$$

then we should find $P = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that $-3x_0 +y_0+z_0 = 0$. Then, $3P$ should be a point of the new plane, and therefore satisfy its new equation.

What's the best way to solve this, and could you explain my what my friend did in his solution?

Comment: convert your plane equation into the Hessian one and determine the variable $d$ such the distance to the other one is $3$

Comment: Would it not be easier to start with a point $\textbf{P}$ on the plane and go in the direction of $$v = 3 \cdot \frac{(3,-1,-1)}{\left\|(3,-1,-1)\right\|}$$  Then get all $X \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $(X-P_1) \cdot v = 0$ where we know we can choose $P_1 = \textbf{P}+v$.

Comment: @Guerlando OCs Your friend's solution makes no sense.  If $P$ satisfies $-3x_0 + y_0 + z_0 = 0$, then so does $3P$, and $5P$.  So it doesn't uniquely identify distance at all.  Your solution sounds perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Mr.Fry why not just post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Seth, I had the thought and intuitively it seemed right, but I didn't work out the specifics so there may be holes.

Comment: @Mr.Fry your comment is definitely correct and it seems to me to be the best way to approach this problem.  In fact for this example we can choose $P=0$ and then it is quite easy to calculate an equation for the plane (i also checked that the equation agrees with the current answer, which has 3 upvotes already)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equation of the plane parallel to the given plane:  $3x-y-z=0$ is $$3x-y-z+c=0 $$
Where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. Now, using $\color{blue}{\text{distance formula for parallel planes}}$ as follows  $$\frac{\left|c-0\right|}{\sqrt{(3)^2+(-1)^2+(-1)^2}}=3$$  $$\left|c\right|=3\sqrt{11}$$ $$c=\pm 3\sqrt{11}$$  Hence, there are two parallel planes at distance $3$ on either side to the given plane: $3x-y-z=0$. Hence, the equations of unknown planes  $$\color{blue}{3x-y-z\pm3\sqrt{11}=0}$$

**Edit**: In general, the distance between any two parallel planes: $ax+by+cz+d_1=0$ & $ax+by+cz+d_2=0$ is $$=\frac{|d_1-d_2|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

I decided to add the comment I made as a solution. I think this is a bit more intuitive for me. The solution posed by Harish is nice as well and I mean nothing by the statement "would it not be easier" since its all about personal preference.

[image]